# Calling Mathematica from Lazarus/Freepascal

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, interoperability

I will appreciate if anyone can give me an hint about freepascal and mathematica mathlink communication.

I'd like to build a Form using Lazarus/freepascal that call mathkernel.

I'm trying to move away from ExcelLink-component to a home made Form.

Comment: You need to find out how to call C functions from FreePascal, and create an interface for calling the MathLink libraries.  The bulk of the work is not related to Mathematica: what you need is calling C functions from FreePascal.  You need FreePascal (and C) expertise, not Mathematica expertise, so I'd suggest asking about that problem on StackOverflow instead.

Comment: @Szabloc Thanks I found a document on [link](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Creating_bindings_for_C_libraries) about an utility to convert .h heder file to pascal unit.